# String comparison not working in fishshell function

Tags: shell, fish

Getting error `Expected a combining operator like '-a' at index 2`

my function is

```
set fish_git_dirty_color red
set fish_git_not_dirty_color green

# Defined interactively
function gph --description 'alias gph=git push origin HEAD'
    echo '~~~~~Pushing to github~~~~'
    set -l branch (git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e '\* ' | sed 's/^..\(.*\)/\1/')
    echo $branch
    if test [ $branch = "master" ]
        echo (set_color $fish_git_dirty_color)$branch(set_color normal)
        echo "if block"
    else
        echo (set_color $fish_git_not_dirty_color)$branch(set_color normal)
        echo 'else block'
    end
end
```

Somehow it is using else block even when I'm on master branch

Comment: Use this to get the current git branch: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null`

Comment: But the real problem is this: use **either** `test` **or** `[ ... ]`, not both.